# In PHP how to sort a file in reverse?

Tags: php, arrays, file, sorting, array-reverse

i have a text (text.txt) file like this:

```
shir
beer
geer
deer
```

i have also a php page with that source:

```
<?php
foreach (glob("*.txt") as $filename) {   
    $file = $filename;
    $contents = file($file); 
    $reverse = array_reverse($file, true);
    $string = implode("<br>" , $contents);
    echo $string;
    echo "<br></br>";
}
?>
```

I want that in the php page it will show:

```
deer
geer
beer
shir
```

from the end of the file to the beginning.

thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you are reversing the file name and not the contents.

Do

```
$reverse = array_reverse($content); // you can drop 2nd arg.
$string = implode("<br>" , $reverse);
```

in place of

```
$reverse = array_reverse($file, true); 
$string = implode("<br>" , $contents);
```

Also you can remove the temp variables from you script and do:

```
foreach (glob("*.txt") as $filename) {   
    echo implode("<br>" , array_reverse(file($filename))) . "<br></br>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
foreach (glob("*.txt") as $filename) {   
    $file = $filename;
    $contents = file($file); 
    $reverse = array_reverse($contents, true);
    $string = implode("<br>" , $reverse);
    echo $string;
    echo "<br></br>";
}
?>
```

Your result was a $contents, without reverse.

Comment: This still reverses `$file`, not `$contents` as desired.

Comment: Sometimes these things are easy to miss. :) Thanks for fixing it!